# Compare only date component in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I need to select some entities using HQL filtering by time. But I need to compare only date component without time. For example 1.1.2011 12.00 and 1.1.2011 13.20 must be equal.

What operator can I use?

```
@Query("FROM Item item " +
  "WHERE item.date [equality by date operator] :date " )
List<Item> findByDate(@Param("date") Date date);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you do not mind DB-specific functions, you'd be able to do this (using Oracle as an example).

```
@Query("FROM Item item WHERE trunc(item.date) = trunc(:date) " )
List<Item> findByDate(@Param("date") Date date);
```

You can use this because the OracleDialect registers `trunc` as a `StandardSQLFunction` and Oracle's `TRUNC` removes the time component of a date.

Comment: In Oracle to avoid errors you can call `trunc(item.date,'YYYY')`  to avoid some errors.

Answer (score 10):

If you do mind the DB-specific functions (and you should) then work with 2 dates:

1. from date = date with time set to midnight
2. to date = date with time set to 23:59:59.999

then query for dates >= from date and <= to date

Comment: I am using oracle db and its better for me to use trunc. Tnx for our answer

Comment: Fine but if you want to unit test with an in-memory DB where this is not supported you will be stuck.

Answer (score -2):

```
"Select col from Table t where t.date = CURRENT_DATE()"
```

try this .